# Ionic 4: How to overflow div from Ionic Header or Toolbar?

Tags: ionic-framework

[image]

I want create a drop down menu or popover within ionic toolbar. I tried with several ways but can not solve. Its always hidden like bellow,

[image]

I trying css like bellow,

```
.popover{
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 350px;
   width: 150px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 99999999;
   background: yellow;
}

ion-header{
  contain: none;
}
ion-toolbar{
  contain: none;
}
```

Please give me a suggestion or an alternative idea. Please do not give any predictive answer if you are not familiar with **ionic**.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I face the same.

Comment: Yes, I did.. I created custom header with ion-grid.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I had to make a searchbar overflow underneath the header (design thing). I was struggling a while and it popped in place suddenly when I place the searchbar outside of the toolbar and gave it position absolute:

```html
<ion-head>
  <ion-toolbar>
     <!-- My stuff here -->
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
<ion-header>
```

My css looks like this:

```css
ion-toolbar {
  display: flex; // I need this for something else, but maybe has an influence
}

ion-searchbar {
  padding: 0 1em .5em 1em;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 99999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: helpful. moving it got me a good step closer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Ionic 4 but on Ionic 5, a solution would be this when you debug on the console :

```
ion-toolbar {
    contain: none;

    .toolbar-container {
        overflow: visible;
        contain: none;
    }
}
```

However, the `.toolbar-container` is an element in the shadow dom of the `<ion-toolbar>` component and its `overflow` and `contain` properties are not css variables and there is no [part attribute](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/) on this element neither. So there is actually no way to override those properties.

I'm considering using this package, but for me it seems like overkill to use js and timeout for setting a pretty simple style... :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shadow-dom-inject-styles

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for the solution. Here is how I managed to fixed it in react. It's a bit hacky solution, but most likely the only one ATM.

First we need to style the toolbar (pass a className or style to  component:

```
.your-toolbar-classname {
     overflow: visible!important;
     contain: none!important;
}
```

Then we have to also style the shadow-root parts. Se we can use the useEffect after the header is mounted and set the style

```
// Header.tsx

...
    useEffect(() => {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML =
        '.toolbar-container { overflow: visible!important; contain: none!important; }';
    toolbarRef.current.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
}, []);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use ion-menu, its a build in ionic component 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu

There is also ion-popover

You should look at the ionic docs before posting on stack

Comment: ion-menu is not popover from header

Comment: You said, pop over OR menu, and asked for suggestions, really a down vote